# Floating & resizing a libGDX/lwjgl application in Xmonad

Tags: eclipse, lwjgl, libgdx, xmonad

I recently switched to using Xmonad as my window manager.

When I run my libGDX/lwjgl app using eclipse, it's automatically tiled by Xmonad. This creates some problems with the positioning.

I tried running

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

and clicking on the application. It doesn't show any name.

If there's any way to detect these lwjgl applications and float them, let me know.

Thank you.

EDIT: I found that,

```
className =? ""               --> doFloat
```

would float the window, but still it doesn't have the proper size (800x480), any tips on resizing the app would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use `Gdx.graphics.setTitle()` does that give you a visible property to match in xmonad?

Comment: No it still wouldn't give me a visible property match. But I was able to match the property to "" (empty string). The only thing left is to set the default size of the window.